# ES nested query using nested

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below data in ES, how can I query using match_phrase against the name. I want to search aaa and get the below data.

```
"student": {
   "id": "1",
   "name": "bbb",
   "school" : [
      {
        "result" : "50",
         "name" : "aaa school",
      }
   ]
}
```

Index mapping:

```
"student" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "R1634640669477" : {
              "properties" : {
                  "school" : {
                        "type" : "nested",
                        "properties" : {
                            "name" : {
                                 "type" : "keyword"
                            }
                  }
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way to learn this is to set up the query in kibana, then use inspect request and get the elastic search query as json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `match_phrase` query, try out the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "student.school.name": {
        "query": "aaa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not giving any result

Comment: @test can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: Updated in the question